# praat - combine multiple wav files

Tags: concatenation, wav, praat

I have 136 wav files named numerically (1.wav to 136. wav), plus a wav file that contains 2 seconds of silence. I would like to combine them as follows, generating several other files:

```
1 + silence + 2 + silence (copy) + 3 
1 + silence + 2 + silence (copy) + 4
2 + silence + 1 + silence (copy) + 3 
2 + silence + 1 + silence (copy) + 4

5 + silence + 6 + silence + (copy) + 7
5 + silence + 6 + silence + (copy) + 8
6 + silence + 5 + silence + (copy) + 7
6 + silence + 5 + silence + (copy) + 8
```

I have the script below, which combines the files as follows:

```
1 + silence + 2 + silence + (copy) + 1 (copy)
1 + silence + 2 + silence + (copy) + 2 (copy)
2 + silence + 1 + silence + (copy) + 1 (copy)
2 + silence + 1 + silence + (copy) + 1 (copy)


3 + silence + 4 + silence + (copy) + 2 (copy)
3 + silence + 4 + silence + (copy) + 3 (copy)
4 + silence + 3 + silence + (copy) + 3 (copy)
4 + silence + 3 + silence + (copy) + 4 (copy)



str = Create Strings as file list... soundlist 'directory$'/*.wav
num_file = Get number of strings

#writeInfoLine: num_file

#Copy... silence2
for i to num_file
    selectObject: str
    fileName$ = Get string: i
    #writeInfoLine: fileName$
    n_fn$ = fileName$
    num_c = number(n_fn$ - ".wav")
    n_sound_file$ = string$(num_c+1) + ".wav"


    if num_c mod 2 == 1
        cp_f1$ = fileName$ - ".wav" + "cp"
        cp_f2$ = n_sound_file$ - ".wav" + "cp"
        cp_sil1$ = "sil1"
        f_file$ = "Sound " + fileName$ - ".wav"
        s_file$ = "Sound " + n_sound_file$ - ".wav"
        f_file2$ = "Sound " + cp_f1$
        s_file2$ = "Sound " + cp_f2$
        sil_file$ = "Sound " + "silence"
        sil_file2$ = "Sound " + "sil1"
        writeInfoLine: cp_f1$
        new_f1$ = "Sound " + f_file$ + "_sil_" + s_file$ + "_sil_" + f_file$+".wav"
        new_f2$ = "Sound " + f_file$ + "_sil_" + s_file$ + "_sil_" + s_file$ + ".wav"
        new_f3$ = "Sound " + s_file$ + "_sil_" + f_file$ + "_sil_" + f_file$ + ".wav"
        new_f4$ = "Sound " + s_file$ + "_sil_" + f_file$ + "_sil_" + s_file$ + ".wav"

#########
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + fileName$
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + "silence.wav" 
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + n_sound_file$
        selectObject: sil_file$
        Copy... sil1
        selectObject: f_file$
        Copy... 'cp_f1$'

        selectObject: f_file$
        plusObject: sil_file$
        plusObject: s_file$
        plusObject: sil_file2$
        plusObject: f_file2$

        Concatenate
        Save as WAV file... 'directory$'/'new_f1$'
        removeObject: f_file$, sil_file$,sil_file2$,f_file2$
#########

        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + fileName$
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + "silence.wav" 
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + n_sound_file$
        selectObject: sil_file$
        Copy... sil1
        selectObject: s_file$
        Copy... 'cp_f2$'




        selectObject: f_file$
        plusObject: sil_file$
        plusObject: s_file$
        plusObject: sil_file2$
        plusObject: s_file2$

        Concatenate
        Save as WAV file... 'directory$'/'new_f2$'
        removeObject: f_file$, sil_file$,sil_file2$,s_file2$

#####
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + n_sound_file$
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + "silence.wav" 
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + fileName$
        selectObject: sil_file$
        Copy... sil1
        selectObject: s_file$
        Copy... 'cp_f2$'




        selectObject: s_file$
        plusObject: sil_file$
        plusObject: f_file$
        plusObject: sil_file2$
        plusObject: s_file2$

        Concatenate
        Save as WAV file... 'directory$'/'new_f3$'
        removeObject: s_file$, sil_file$,sil_file2$,s_file2$
####

        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + n_sound_file$
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + "silence.wav" 
        Read from file: directory$+ "/" + fileName$
        selectObject: sil_file$
        Copy... sil1
        selectObject: f_file$
        Copy... 'cp_f1$'




        selectObject: s_file$
        plusObject: sil_file$
        plusObject: f_file$
        plusObject: sil_file2$
        plusObject: f_file2$

        Concatenate
        Save as WAV file... 'directory$'/'new_f4$'





    endif   

endfor

select all
    Remove
```

The script that I have so far divides the files into file named as an odd number and an even number.  For my current purpose, the algorithm would be more complex. I would be grateful if I could get some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I am the author of the mentioned Parselmouth library]*

I am not an expert on Praat scripting, but if you are willing to use Python (and the [Parselmouth library](https://github.com/YannickJadoul/Parselmouth) to access Praat functionality from Python), the following Python code seems to work for me:

```py
import glob
import parselmouth

directory = "/the/directory/of/your/choice"
output_directory = "/the/directory/of/your/choice/output"

all_files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.wav")
n_files = len(all_files) - 1 # Number of files minus 'silence.wav'

def concatenate_and_save(first, second, third):
    silence = parselmouth.Sound(directory + "/silence.wav")
    sound1 = parselmouth.Sound(directory + "/" + str(first) + ".wav")
    sound2 = parselmouth.Sound(directory + "/" + str(second) + ".wav")
    sound3 = parselmouth.Sound(directory + "/" + str(third) + ".wav")
    concatenated = parselmouth.Sound.concatenate([sound1, silence, sound2, silence, sound3])
    concatenated.save(output_directory + "/" + str(first) + "_sil_" + str(second) + "_sil_" + str(third) + ".wav", "WAV")

for i in range(1, n_files+1, 4):
    concatenate_and_save(i, i+1, i+2)
    concatenate_and_save(i, i+1, i+3)
    concatenate_and_save(i+1, i, i+2)
    concatenate_and_save(i+1, i, i+3)
```

Apologies if you needed the code as Praat script, but I do expect it will be possible and straightforward to replicate the idea of this algorithm (i.e., going in steps of 4 through the number of files and then using the right combinations of `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`, and `i+3`, and maybe use a function to not repeat yourself) in a Praat script?